# How to convert integers represented as string to ASCII symbols?

Tags: c++, string, char, integer, converters

I have an input string that can look like this: "126022034056098012". It is a result of concatination of ASCII codes of symbols that I've read from some file. The codes are 126 22 34 56 98 12 for example. The problem is how to decode this string back into characters? Note: the string mustn't contain any delimiters other than digits (\,| and so on). What should I do next?

I figured out a way that uses map of ASCII symbols: key->string with numeric representatoin of ASCII symbol, value->ASCII symbol. In the loop, I accumulate the incoming digits in a string until the string matches some key in the map. When matched, I convert the resulting code into a character. I continue until I run out of input data. But this method works good with strings and txt-files but don't work with binary files.

function that makes string of characters from string of ASCII codes:

```cpp
string Utils::from_number_to_ascii(string number, int size) {
    Utils ut;
    while(number.size() % 3) {
        number = "0" + number;
    }

    string out;
    for (int i = 0; i < size;){
        string st;
        auto it = ut.triple_dict.end();
        while (it == ut.triple_dict.end() && i < size){
            st += number[i++];
            it = ut.triple_dict.find(st);
        }
        out += it->second;
        st = "";
    }
    return out;
}
```

filling the map:

```cpp
Utils::Utils() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
        string s =  to_string(static_cast<int>(i));
        if (s.size() == 1) {
            s = "00" + s;
        } if (s.size() == 2){
            s = "0" + s;
        }
        triple_dict.insert(make_pair(s, static_cast<unsigned char>(i)));
    }
}
```

It's not hard to see that I fill the container with three bytes: if the ASCII code of symbol is two-digit number I append it with "0", if code of symbol is one-digit number I append it with "00" to make code three-digit number. I do this for unambiguous decoding of symbol.

Comment: How would the program know if it has to take the code 126 or 12? Usually, if you're not using delimiters, you would use fixed size (in your example, 3 digits), so actual input should be 126022034056098012. Otherwise, there's no way for your program to know if you input 126126 if you mean 126 126 or 12 61 26 or 126 1 2 6 or 12 6 126... etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I use fixed size of code. I forgot edit my question.

Comment: A problem that interests me is how to apply this method to binary files or how to do it differently.

Comment: What about simply splitting the string every third character and converting each fragment (of 3 characters supposed to be decimal digits) to an int value? That int value will be the ASCII code of the initial character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each ascii code is represented by exactly 3 digits, we can do this pretty easily with a loop:

```
std::string toAscii(char const* digits, size_t size) {
    std::string output(size / 3, '\0');
    for(char& c : output) {
        char d0 = *digits++; // Get 3 digits
        char d1 = *digits++;
        char d2 = *digits++; 

        int ascii_value = (d0 - '0') * 100 + (d1 - '0') * 10 + (d2 - '0'); 
        c = (char)ascii_value; 
    }
    return output; 
}
```

#### Example usage

I have a c-string with the example input, as well as a string with the expected output. This program verifies that they're equal.

```
int main() {
    auto&& input = "126022034056098012";
    std::string expected_output = {char(126), char(22), char(34), char(56), char(98), char(12)};
    std::cout << (toAscii(input, sizeof(input)) == expected_output); // Prints true
}
```

#### Does fstream.write() add '\0' to the end of the file?

**No.** If your string contains the 0 character, it'll add it, but not otherwise. We can test this for ourselves with some pretty short example code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    {
        std::ofstream file("test.txt");
        std::string   message = "Hello!";

        file.write(message.data(), message.length());
        // file gets closed automatically 
    }
    {
        std::ifstream file("test.txt");


        while (file)
        {
            std::cout << file.get() << '\n';
        }
        // file gets closed automatically
    }
}
```

When I compile and run this code, it outputs the following. Each value corresponds to the value of the corresponding character in `"Hello!"`, except for the last one. The `-1` indicates that you've reached the end of the file, but if you were using a method like `file.read` it wouldn't show up. The `\0` doesn't appear anywhere in the file.

```
72
101
0
108
111
33
-1
```

Comment: It is very interesting. Could you tell me, how to write c string (char const*) to binary file without "\0" symbol in the end? Does the fstream.write() write this symbol (\0) or not? Does this command (fstream.write((char *)str.c_str() , str.length());) write string to binary file without end character?

Comment: It writes the string without the '\0'. I added some code to my answer that shows this!